# Trying to understand typeahead.js The Basics code starting with $.each(

Tags: typeahead.js

I am trying to understand how typeahead.js works by reading http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#scrollable-dropdown-menu:

```
 $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
  if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
    matches.push(str);
  }
}
```

How the code above works, I mean what **i** and **str** variables stand for?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: i tried to read documentation, i wasn't clear

Comment: what part wasn't clear?  it's very self explanatory, and provides examples with demos.

Comment: I understood that i stands for index, but I have no idea where str comes from, sorry for the stupid question

Comment: the jquery documentation is one of the most clear that you will find anywhere, but I'll try to summarize the documentation.  if `strs` is a collection of objects, the `.each` performs the same operation on every `str` in the `strs` collection.  the `i` is which `str` it is working on, the `str` is that specific one in the collection.

Comment: Now it is super clear, thanks